Is it Possible to Read From a CockroachDb in a Region if it has Lost Connection to the Other Regions?
If I have CockroachDb replicas in three Kubernetes Clusters in different regions and one of the clusters loses connection to the others, will a app in that cluster still be able to read from the CockroachDb in the same cluster?
For example will the App in Region 1 still be able to read data from CockroachDb, even if it has lost connection to Region 2 and Region 3?
Example Setup
I have tried to find the answer online.

Even if a Kubernetes cluster in CockroachDB loses connection to others, it can still read locally stored data. CockroachDB ensures availability and consistency through its distributed architecture.
